# Youtube Analytics APIs - How do i can fix forbidden 403 error?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get youtube channel stats using Youtube APIs, it is giving me error like below. I have also mentioed the API script that I get from Youtube APIs Explore (API Playground method)

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Forbidden",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

> Request that is being made,(get from Youtube APIs Explorer)

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('API code samples');
$client->setScopes([
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly',
]);

$client->setAuthConfig('YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_FILE.json');
$client->setAccessType('offline');


$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
printf("Open this link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
print('Enter verification code: ');
$authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));


$accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);


$service = new Google_Service_YouTubeAnalytics($client);

$queryParams = [
    'dimensions' => 'ageGroup,gender',
    'endDate' => '2022-01-01',
    'ids' => 'channel==UCTVujeJyggsTZnlnsdaP0dQ',
    'metrics' => 'viewerPercentage',
    'sort' => 'gender,ageGroup',
    'startDate' => '2017-01-01'
];

$response = $service->reports->query($queryParams);
print_r($response);
```

Comment: its an issue with the scope you are picking probably or the channel that you are authorized as i cant seen the request you are making.

Comment: @DaImTo i have update the question. I am trying from youtube apis explorer method

Comment: most of the YouTube API methods don't work with the try me.

Comment: @DaImTo I was doing it with wrong way. I was trying to get stats with channleId even after auth.
I have fixed it via replacing "==MINE".